# How to save custom objects that implements Codable

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

It's now easier with Swift 4 to encode / decode to and from [JSON or Properties list](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

But I can't find how to encode to Data using Codable, without using Objective-C methods `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder`.

Considering this simple class:

```
struct Question: Codable {
    var title: String
    var answer: Int
    var question: Int
}
```

How can I encode it to Data using `CodingKeys` and not `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder`?

EDIT:
I also need to be able to deserialize objects previously saved in userdefaults using NSKeyedArchiver.

Comment: It's described in detail (and in Swift) in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Comment: Sorry if my question was not complete, but I need to deserialize objects that have been saved using NSKeyedArchiver. So I think JSONEncoder or PropertyListEncoder won't work there, no?

Comment: @Damien you mean saving to userdefaults and retreiving from it as you do with NSKeyedArchiver?

Comment: @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃 yes exactly, sorry if it was unclear

Answer (score 30):

Well, you no longer need `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Try this:

```
let questionObj = Question(title: "WWDC, 2017", answer: 1,question:1)
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(questionObj) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "K_Question")
}
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let questionData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "K_Question"),
    let question = try? decoder.decode(Question.self, from: questionData) {
    print(question.title)
    print(question.answer)
    print(question.question)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So that means we can use JSONEncoder as well as PropertyListEncoder? Any idea which one is faster?

Comment: I have not tried PropertyListEncoder..Please ask a separate question for it.

Comment: How to decode Array of Questions Object from JSONDecoder?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5**: a great simple extension for **UserDefaults**:

```
extension UserDefaults {

    func save<T: Codable>(_ object: T, forKey key: String) {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encodedObject = try? encoder.encode(object) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedObject, forKey: key)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }

    func getObject<T: Codable>(forKey key: String) -> T? {
        if let object = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let decodedObject = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: object) {
                return decodedObject
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Usage**

**save**

```
UserDefaults.standard.save(currentUser, forKey: "currentUser")
```

**get**

```
let user: User? = UserDefaults.standard.getObject(forKey: "currentUser")
```

Comment: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be achieved via JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder.

```
struct Question: Codable {
    var title: String
    var answer: Int
    var question: Int
}

let questionObj = Question(title: "Swift", answer: "Open Source",question:1)


let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(questionObj) {
    if let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(json)
    }

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let decoded = try? decoder.decode(Question.self, from: encoded) {
        print(decoded)
    }
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't work - the Question value doesn't comply with codable / decodable

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Question: Codable {
    var title: String
    var answer: Int
    var question: Int
}

class UserDefaults_Question {
    static let key = "myapp.trick.question"

    static var value: UserDefaults_Question? {
        get {
            guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key) else {
                print("no model for key: \(key)")
                return nil
            }
            guard let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserDefaults_Question.self, from: data) else {
                print("failed to decode model for key: \(key)")
                return nil
            }
            print("did load model for key: \(key)")
            return model
        }
        set {
            guard let value = newValue, let data: Data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(value) else {
                print("removing model for key: \(key)")
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
                return
            }
            print("inserting model for key: \(key)")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

UserDefaults_Question.value = Question(title: "Next President", answer: 666, question: -1)
```