# How to archive data of UICollectionView elements

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm creating an app that allows users to create sheet of notes.
In order to make this I've created a UICollectionViewController and each element is an object of the class Books.
Then I create an array that contains all this books.
My Question is: How can I memorize books, with their name, type..., in device's memory?

I try to use:

```
    let booksDefault = UserDefaults.standard

    if (booksDefault.value(forKey: "booksDefault") != nil) {
        books = booksDefault.value(forKey: "booksDefault") as! [Books]
    }
        let booksDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        booksDefault.setValue(books, forKey: "booksDefault")
        booksDefault.synchronize()
```

but it doesn't work.
Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but important: you don't need `.synchronize()`. It's obsolete. Actually it can even cause lags if the defaults domain is large. The documentation now explains that the system itself immediately saves the value without ever needing to manually synchronize.

Comment: Thank you but Do you know why if I use this method my code crash?

Comment: Your code should works, only if `Books` is NSCoding compliant. If not, there should be an error saying so. And I think that should have an error, do you mind showing it? That's an important part of the question! Could you also explain how do you know it's not working, what you mean by that?

Comment: Did you try to serialize objects before saving?

Comment: My idea is to save books (with its name) and in order to do this I’ve created an array that contains books that the user create. I tried to save that array, but the code crash

Comment: @PietroPutelli If the code crash, there should be an error in console. Read it, if you don't understand it, give it here. But I strongly guess that `Books` class is not `NSCoding` compliant. Read "how to save Object into (NS)UserDefaults + NSCoding"

Comment: So maybe in this way is more clear: do you know app notability? So I santo to create an app like that where the user can write and then save on the device’s memory these notes

Comment: Try to using `Codable ` check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44496937/9315978